# Как присвоить ячейкам значения массива?

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть ячейки в html:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И есть двумерный массив, который заполняется true или false. То есть, когда нажимаешь на ячейку, то вместо картинки на bg будет надпись: false или true.

JS:

```
    let appleCells = [];
function getRandomBoolean(min, max) {
    return (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) === 0);

}


    for (let i=0; i<8;i++)
    {
        let ArrayCells = [];
        for(let j=0; j<6;j++)
        {
            ArrayCells[j] = getRandomBoolean();
           
        }
        appleCells.push(ArrayCells)
    }
```

Мне нужно присвоить каждый элемент массива к ячейкам, а при клике на определенную ячейку должно показывать, что она false или true.

Пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну и там выше по аналогии. Как мне привязать массив к этим ячейкам?

UPD:

HTML:

```html
 <div class="apple-container">
        <div class="apple-grid">
            <button class="cell" type="button">

            </button>
            <button class="cell" type="button">

            </button>
            <button class="cell" type="button">

            </button>
            <button class="cell" type="button">

            </button>
            <button class="cell" type="button">

            </button>
            <button class="cell" type="button">

            </button>
            
        </div>
        <div class="apple-grid">
            <button class="cell" type="button">

            </button>
            <button class="cell" type="button">

            </button>
            <button class="cell" type="button">

            </button>
            <button class="cell" type="button">

            </button>
            <button class="cell" type="button">

            </button>
            <button class="cell" type="button">

            </button>

        </div>
        <div class="apple-grid">
            <button class="cell" type="button">

            </button>
            <button class="cell" type="button">

            </button>
            <button class="cell" type="button">

            </button>
            <button class="cell" type="button">

            </button>
            <button class="cell" type="button">

            </button>
            <button class="cell" type="button">

            </button>

        </div>
        <div class="apple-grid">
            <button class="cell" type="button">

            </button>
            <button class="cell" type="button">

            </button>
            <button class="cell" type="button">

            </button>
            <button class="cell" type="button">

            </button>
            <button class="cell" type="button">

            </button>
            <button class="cell" type="button">

            </button>

        </div>
        <div class="apple-grid">
            <button class="cell" type="button">

            </button>
            <button class="cell" type="button">

            </button>
            <button class="cell" type="button">

            </button>
            <button class="cell" type="button">

            </button>
            <button class="cell" type="button">

            </button>
            <button class="cell" type="button">

            </button>

        </div>
        <div class="apple-grid">
            <button class="cell" type="button">

            </button>
            <button class="cell" type="button">

            </button>
            <button class="cell" type="button">

            </button>
            <button class="cell" type="button">

            </button>
            <button class="cell" type="button">

            </button>
            <button class="cell" type="button">

            </button>

        </div>
        <div class="apple-grid">
            <button class="cell" type="button">

            </button>
            <button class="cell" type="button">

            </button>
            <button class="cell" type="button">

            </button>
            <button class="cell" type="button">

            </button>
            <button class="cell" type="button">

            </button>
            <button class="cell" type="button">

            </button>

        </div>
        <div class="apple-grid">
            <button class="cell" type="button">

            </button>
            <button class="cell" type="button">

            </button>
            <button class="cell" type="button">

            </button>
            <button class="cell" type="button">

            </button>
            <button class="cell" type="button">

            </button>
            <button class="cell" type="button">

            </button>

       
            
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Могли бы вы добавить еще ваш html с данными ячейками? (желательно в сниппет)

Comment: @RoNULL Дополнил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сократить ваш HTML и совместить создание массива с отрисовкой дерева элементов + назначением событием нажатия мышки на элемент.

По нажатию мыши, будет выводиться текст true или false, который возвращается от вашей функции `getRandomBoolean`.

Стилей вы не указали, поэтому я их придумал :)

```js
function getRandomBoolean() {
  return (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) === 0);
}

const pole = document.getElementById('pole');
for (let i=0; i<8; i++) {
  const line = document.createElement('div');
  line.classList.add('apple-grid');
  for (let j=0; j<6;j++) {
    const box = document.createElement('button');
    box.classList.add('cell');
    const val = getRandomBoolean();

    function ev(e) {
      const res = document.createElement('div');
      res.innerHTML = val.toString();
      e.currentTarget.appendChild(res);
      e.currentTarget.removeEventListener('click', ev);
    }
    box.addEventListener('click', ev);
    line.appendChild(box);
  }
  pole.appendChild(line);
}
```

```css
  .cell {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #b0ff63;
    background-size: contain;

  }

  .apple-grid {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
  }
```

```html
<div id="pole" class="apple-container">

</div>
```